# How to remove thick border from <thead> and <tfoot> in bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

how do I remove that rather unecessary thick border from the `<thead>` & `<tfoot>` in bootstrap 4?

I saw a forum post about it in Bootstrap 5, but I'm using bootstrap 4 and that fix didn't seem to work for me.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: you could override it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crush the bootstrap css code with the code below to remove the border.

```
<style>
  th {
     border-width: thin !important;
  }
</style>
```